# Bumper cracked after 6 months being repaired at bodyshop

Tags: nissan, parts, bumper

I took my car in to have a front bumper repaired on a 2010 Nissan Rogue.  The bodyshop took almost 3 weeks before they actually got it right.  The paint was off and from the original from the beginning.  Afters I took the car in for a buff and hand wax after I got the car back.  I noticed over the weekend there is a crack in the bumper the same side the bodyshop had so much trouble trying to repair. The bodyshop ordered a OEM bumper.  My question is would the bumper still be under warranty and would the bodyshop still be responsible for repairing it.

Comment: We cannot answer this question because this depends on when the repair happened, what terms were the repairs done under, and who handled the whole process. Your only option is to talk to the body shop directly or to your insurance company *if* they handled the process. Good luck.

Comment: The repairs happened 9/23/15.  The terms were to replace front bumper and paint.

Comment: would the OEM bumper still be under warranty

Comment: I can't say for sure because it depends on what kind of warranty the body shop provided. :(

Comment: Most body shops have a lifetime warranty on their work ... look on their website and see. If it does, take it back and make them do it right. If this was done as part of insurance repair and the shop doesn't want to honor that, go through your insurance and let them know.

Comment: I agree with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. The squeaky wheel gets the grease!